# How to recover/restore corrupted Innodb data files?

Tags: mysql, recovery, restore

A while ago, my Windows 7 system on which a MySQL Server 5.5.31 was running crashed and corrupted the InnoDB database. The weekly backup that's available does not cover all the tables that were created in the meantime, therefore I would endeavor to recover as much as possible from the data. Right after the crash, I copied the whole data folder of MySQL to an external drive. I would like use this as the starting point for my rescue attempts.

In the following I'll describe the steps of my (not yet convincing) rescue attempt so and would be thankful for any comments or guidance on how to improve it:

1. I've now done a fresh install of MySQL Server 5.5.31 on another PC
2. I stop the MySQL service with "net stop MySQL" at the command prompt.
3. I already figured that I need to adjust the size of the innodb log file in the my.ini file as it deviates (256 MB) from the default value (19MB).
4. In the my.ini, I also set innodb_force_recovery=6
5. In the data folder of the fresh installation, I overwrite the ibdata1, iblogfile0, iblogfile1 files with those recovered from the crashed machine. I also copy the relevant database (UPDATE: and the mysql) folders into here (NOT the standard <strike>mysql,</strike> test and performance folders).
6. I start the MySQL service with "net start MySQL".
7. I go into MySQL Workbench, open my server instance, go to Data Export, basically leave the default settings, and have every table of my databases exported as an individual dump file. I also set stored procedures to be dumped. Otherwise I do not change the default settings there.
8. I start the dump process; it makes its way through 43 out of 195 tables. Of these 43,

   - some cannot be recovered yielding an error "*mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table '...whatever...' doesn't exist when doing LOCK TABLES*",
   - but many can. I assume that when the dump does not yield any error, the table's data is non-corrupted.
     Then, after the 44th, all the other table dumps fail as it is reported that the server cannot be connected to anymore:
     "*mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when trying to connect

     Operation failed with exitcode 2*"
     These errors then go on for all the remaining tables from the 44th to the 195th.
     For the 44th table itself, the error is the following: "*mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `...table 44...` at row: 57*". So it seems that for this table corruption is or begins at row 57.

Now to my questions:

- Why is the connection breaking down given that innodb_force_recovery is set to 6?
- How to proceed? I worked out what the 44th table was where the connection was lost and can try to resume the process from the 45th table. But isn't there a better way to do it?
- Once the data has been copied and the server restarts well, should I just try a dump of each table or what alternatives are there?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE: Additional notes for my later reference
- When re-creating stored routines backed up using SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE ... and SHOW CREATE FUNCTION ..., they must be imported using  `DELIMITER //
(create procedure code of procedure 1)//
(create procedure code of procedure 2)//
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Check this out, seriously: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/05/13/connecting-orphaned-ibd-files/ Super helpful. Our ibdata1 was trashed and this helped us get righted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the MySQL error log.  It looks like trying to read table 44 is actually crashing the server.

"Lost connection to MySQL server during query" is (or should be) heart-stopping time for a MySQL DBA because it often means that whatever your query just did has actually crashed the server.

The subsequent messages seem to bear this out:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when
trying to connect
Operation failed with exitcode 2
```

A quick test of mysqldump on Windows 7 against a MySQL server *that is not running* returns exactly that same error and exits with `%ERRORLEVEL%` set to 2.  The nature of error 10061 can be found with [the `perror` utility](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/perror.html).

```
C:\>perror 10061
Win32 error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

...so, check the MySQL error log.  What's likely happening is that you're hitting corruption severe enough that in spite of `innodb_force_recovery`, the MySQL Server is crashing.  I will then usually restart on its own, but this takes time so may not complete before mysqldump gets an IP connection refused on the subsequent connection attempts.  This should all show up in the error log.

> I assume that when the dump does not yield any error, the table's data is non-corrupted.

Incorrect assumption.  If the dump does not yield any error, it could also mean that that `innodb_force_recovery` allowed the server to retrieve *some* of the data.  A "successful" dump of a table only means it's not corrupted so severely that `innodb_force_recovery` can't survive it.

> `1 (SRV_FORCE_IGNORE_CORRUPT)`
>
> Let the server run even if it detects a corrupt page. Try to make `SELECT * FROM tbl_name` jump over corrupt index records and pages, which helps in dumping tables.
>
> <sup>http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html</sup>

Again, you should see chatter from InnoDB in the MySQL error log.

Final suggestion, don't use workbench.  Use the `mysql` command line client to explore the server schemata and use `mysqldump` directly from the command line to try to restore individual schemas or individual databases.

---

**update/additional:**

> how do you recover stored procedures? I get an error because they access corrupt tables

It shouldn't be because the procedures access corrupt tables, because stored procedures and functions aren't validated against their referenced tables in the way views are (drop a table that a view references, and then `SHOW CREATE VIEW` doesn't work -- the same isn't the case with procs or functions)... MySQL doesn't care whether tables referenced by stored procedures and functions even exist (except at runtime)... however, unlike view definitions, which are stored in individual files, the definitions of procedures and functions are stored in the `proc` table in the `mysql` schema, which is a MyISAM table... so I would expect that you'd see error messages referencing that table and `CHECK TABLE mysql.proc;` and [`REPAIR TABLE mysql.proc;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/repair-table.html) might get you going again.  Note that the version of MySQL Server that you're using for your recovery needs to be the same release series (e.g. 5.5) or the table definition of `mysql.proc` will be wrong... that shouldn't be the issue here, since if I read the question correctly, the crashed server and the recovery server are both 5.5.31.

If you can `SELECT * FROM mysql.proc` then you can retrieve the definitions that way if for some reason the `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` statement doesn't work.

> And what options for a (partial) rescue are there for the tables that yielded an error in the dumps?

It depends on the nature and scope of the errors encountered.  One option, [discussed here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/), involves repeated `INSERT ... SELECT ... LIMIT ... OFFSET`, extracting blocks of rows from readable pages into a MyISAM table (because you can't write to an InnoDB table while `innodb_force_recovery` is on).  There's also the [Percona Data Recovery Tool for InnoDB](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/innodb-data-recovery-tool%3astart), though I have never had occasion to use it.

Comment: Thank you, I learn a lot from your post. Before I read it, I proceeded in the way that I restarted the server every time it crashed and skipped the files that led to the crash. I kept track of all tables that yielded any error (with or without a subsequent crash). The bottom line is that about 10% of all tables are corrupt. After having read your message, I now know that I should repeat the dump for the remaining 90% of tables while setting innodb_force_recovery back to 0.   On another note, how do you recover stored procedures? I get an error because they access corrupt tables.

Comment: And what options for a (partial) rescue are there for the tables that yielded an error in the dumps?

Comment: Ok, having dumped again the 90% of tables that were not rejected earlier now with no innodb_force_recovery setting whatsoever in my my.ini file, the result is confirmed - all files were dumped successfully, it made no difference.

Comment: Hi, when I was writing about the dump throwing an error with the stored procedures this referred to the --routines option of mysqldump that indeed fails as it appears to check the availability of tables. However, SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE works and mysql.proc was not defective - just needed to copy the mysql folder from the corrupted installation along with my database folders to the data folder of the recovery installation.